# How to make all resources local?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I do web-app with Nuxt.js and Vuetify addon.

It should work without internet. Now I get error while download css and fonts:

[image]

How do I make all resources local?

Comment: Can you show us some of your configuration (`package.json`, `nuxt.config.js` are a great start)? Hard to help you with just this. Also, what did you tried so far?

Comment: It's default, as out from box

Comment: What is your question so? You do want a tutorial on how to achieve this from scratch? This is not how SO works. Hence your question should be closed. If you do have a specific tech issue, we can help. We are not supposed to make all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid question, not sure why the comments state otherwise, it's just not very clearly formulated. He is asking how he could load fonts & css locally.
Vuetify will automatically attempt to fetch fonts & icons from a CDN (which you see if you click on the request & check the request URL).
You have to install the icons&the fonts locally from NPM.
Here is how you install the icons locally.

Installing icons:
npm install material-design-icons

in nuxt.config.js
Add the css globally

```
 css : [
       '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
    ],

 buildModules: [
      '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
      ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { iconfont: 'mdi' }]
    ]
```

As for the fonts, you will need to use a similar approach if you want Vuetify to load the default fonts locally. I personally use nuxt-webfont-loader, however that does indeed use a CDN but does it async. You could try to experiment with the vuetify settings, for example by disabling the default ones and adding it to the assets folder which is common in Nuxt:

```
vuetify: {
  treeShake: true,
  defaultAssets: {
    font: false,
    icons: 'mdi',
    },
}
```

Comment: There is a community reason of closing a question aka "asking for tutorials". Here, the OP did absolutely no effort into his question and showed 0 research or attempt to achieve it by himself. Just coming and asking on how to do things is not the good way of doing things here. On top of that, I could totally answer his questions but it depends on what he is trying to do exactly with Vuetify/his fonts and also, yeah the damn 10% of work required from him.